# How do I add a javascript or jquery code to an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm using v1.5 of angularjs.
My problem is that whenever I try and animate a directive, especially with jquery, the directive doesn't budge.

```
Mine
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zbeoyvL/

Im having a hard time implementing the angular js but its based off of:

```
Example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2x6s/3/

Comment: That's a tough question to answer without sample code (maybe even a fiddle to work with).  There is no restriction on what js/jquery you use within a directive. But - HOW you implement it can be tricky.

Comment: What directive? What jQuery code? Nobody is going to guess at what you have

Comment: Updated @bri . Thank you

Comment: When the site says that a jsfiddle link alone is not enough and you should post the code in the question, it really means that you should post the code in the question. It doesn't mean you should try to find a way to go around it.

Comment: Why would you need a timer running 100 times per second to see if element is being hovered and not just use mouse events? Doesn't seem very efficient

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I was in a rush and it was immature of me to find a loop hole. @Juhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to generate your HTML twice, one in the HTML itself and the other in the 'template' part of your directive. I'd recommend just showing your projects in the HTML directly since you are using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="projtrack" id="projtrack" ng-repeat="project in projects">
<div projects-info class="projcontainer"><img class="boximg" ng-src="{{ project.img }}"><p> {{ project.description }}</p></div>
</div>
```

Then you can make a directive that is an attribute, which can contain the jquery you want to trigger for the element with that attribute. Notice the div with class 'projcontainer' has an attribute 'project-info'.

```
app.directive('projectsInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function( scope, element, attr) {
        // put your jquery here
        // eg
        element.show();
    }
  };
```

});